# Create a constructor which use another class

Tags: java

I try to create a template object of task using existing task object. When i use a special constructor I get the error:

> incompatible types: Task cannot be converted to TaskTemplate

Here is the code I'm using the create the TaskTemplate:

```
TaskTemplate bean = new TaskTemplate(newTask);
```

Here is the constructor I'm calling:

```
public TaskTemplate(Task task) {
    this.setTitle(task.getTitle());
    this.setDate(task.getDate());
}
```

But when I set all properties in the place where object is created everything is ok.

```
TaskTemplate bean = new TaskTemplate();
bean.setTitle(newTask.getTitle());
bean.setDate(newTask.getDate());
```

Why does it happen?
How can I create a constructor which will get a task and create a template?

Comment: Are you sure the type of `newTask` is Task and not TaskTemplate?

Comment: Any chance you need to rebuild your project? This kind of error can happen when the compiled class differs from the source and recent changes (such as creating a constructor( are not reflected.

Comment: did you want to do like http://ideone.com/K1lvOZ ?

Comment: @Bohemian omg thanks. Forgot to rebuild the part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that you need to rebuild your project.

This kind of problem can happen when the compiled class the calling code is using is out of date with the source code you are viewing, causing great consternation when recent changes (such as creating a new constructor) do not seem to exist from the perspective of the calling code.

Most IDEs automatically rebuild as you code: Check that your IDE is configured to build automatically. If you aren't using an IDE, consider using one.